# Is it ok to use wcout to print char*?

Tags: c++, iostream

Consider this line:

```
std::wcout << "Hello World!";
```

Is it OK to pass `char*` or `char` to wide stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are ok because the wide stream has multiple overloads.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't really sure, and couldn't find anything on the Web!

Comment: Dinkumware documentation shows two overloads in particular: `operator<<(basic_ostream<Elem, Tr>& ostr, const Elem *str)` and `operator<<(basic_ostream<Elem, Tr>& ostr, const char *str)`. This shows that any `ostream` can accept basic `char` pointers as well as pointers to its templated character type. In your case, Ara, `Elem` is `wchar_t`. http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=ostream.html